# How to delete ADS (alternate data stream) in c++

Tags: c, winapi, ntfs

I have a file lets say "c:\file1.txt" that has an ADS file lets say stm so  "c:\file1.txt:stm" now I want to delete the stm without modifying file1

I read somewhere that I need to have an old copy of file1.txt without ADS in order to remove the ADS by replacing file1 with stream with the one that doesnt have one ... is there a better and clean way of doing so ?

Comment: Cheap trick: Copy the file to a FAT drive and back :-) [LADS](http://www.heysoft.de/en/software/lads.php) may be a useful tool, too.

Comment: I am creating a tool to do that...I need a clean way, not adhoc

Comment: What about using the Windows API then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is delete the stream by name.  Using the Windows API that would be:

```
DeleteFile("c:\\file1.txt:stm");
```

You could use plenty of other APIs to do the same thing though, or the command line.

Helpful reference: http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml

Comment: +1 Alternate Data Streams can be treated exactly like a normal file: delete, move, copy, read and write all work using the standard API functions. Other data streams are unaffected (unless you delete the 'main' stream, in which case all the alternate streams go with it.) You can also use the [StrmExt tool from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/6/fc6943eb-790a-44aa-b32d-14ed7e22fd5d/ntfsext.exe) to create/delete ADS's from Windows Explorer.

Comment: Ty, I didnt think it is as simple as this :p

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest method may be to use the [Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440) program from the [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals)
 website.